# Setting pointer out of it's memory range

Tags: c++

I'm writing some code to do bitmap blending and my function has a lot of options for it. I decided to use `switch` to handle those options, but then I needed to either put `switch` inside a loop (I read that it affects performance) or to assign loop for each `switch` case (makes code way too big). I decided to do this using third way (see below):

```
/* When I need to use static value */

BYTE *pointerToValue = (BYTE*)&blendData.primaryValue;
BYTE **pointerToReference = &pointerToValue;
*pointerToReference = *pointerToReference - 3;

/* When I need srcLine's 4th value (where srcLine is a pointer to BYTE array) */

BYTE **pointerToReference = &srcLine;

while (destY2 < destY1) {
    destLine = destPixelArray + (destBytesPerLine * destY2++) + (destX1 * destInc);
    srcLine = srcPixelArray + (srcBytesPerLine * srcY2++) + (srcX1 * srcInc);
    for (LONG x = destX1; x < destX2; x++, destLine += destInc, srcLine += srcInc) {
        BYTE neededValue = *(*pointerToReference + 3); //not yet implemented
        destLine[0] = srcLine[0];
        destLine[1] = srcLine[1];
        destLine[2] = srcLine[2];
        if (diffInc == BOTH_ARE_32_BIT)
            destLine[3] = srcLine[3];
    }
}
```

Sometimes I might need to use `srcLine[3]` or `blendData.primaryValue`. `srcLine[3]` can be accessed easily with `*(*pointerToReference + 3)`, however to access `blendData.primaryValue` I need to reduce pointer by 3 in order to keep the same expression (`*(*pointerToReference + 3)`).

So here are my questions:

1. Is it safe to set pointer out of its memory range if later it is
   going to brought back?
2. I'm 100% sure that it won't be used when it's out of range, but can
   I be sure that it won't cause any kind of access violation?
3. Maybe there is some kind of similar alternative to use one variable
   to capture a value of `srcLine[3]` or `blendData.primaryValue`
   without `if()`, like it's done in my code sample?

Comment: As long as you do not dereference the pointer you should be fine.

Comment: Are you sure the performance of a `switch` inside a loop is *that bad*?  I feel like this might be [premature optimisation](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/a/80092).

Comment: @drescherjm: Bet you someone's gonna write *undefined behavior* in just about 2 seconds from now (SO users love UB).

Comment: I'd probably opt to write the code nicely first (put a switch inside the loop), and see if it's fast enough for you...  as they say: [premature optimization is the root of all evil](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?PrematureOptimization)

Comment: The code sample doesn't even make sense. It uses `pointerToReferences` to set `neededValue` but it never uses `neededValue` again (the variable goes out of scope at the end of the `for` loop), so what is the point of all these tricks?

Comment: @Helix: "Maybe there is some kind of similar alternative that I'm not aware of?" - Maybe, but we sure as hell are not aware of what you want to do to begin with, since you didn't bother to mention it.

Comment: @DavidK: `neededValue` is not implemented yet as I'm yet to how to approach it.

Comment: @Mr.Llama: unfortunately this function will be used almost every time and it has to be optimized to work as fast as possible.

Comment: @barakmanos: I agree that 3rd question is way too abstract at best without complete code sample. But I'll try to make it more specific.

Comment: If runtime performance is really that critical in this one loop, it may make sense to write two or more versions of the loop, each version optimized for the particular conditions under which it will be executed. I don't normally favor duplication of code, but in this case the maintenance cost incurred by the incredibly obscure logic in this code fragment outweighs the cost incurred by additional code, in my opinion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because of #2, no usage, the answer to #1 is yes, it is perfectly safe.  Because of #1, then, there is no need for #3.  :-)

An access violation could only happen if the pointer were actually used.